# Python for loop with non desired results

Tags: python, loops

I am supposed to get an integer input from the command line and have a loop outputting:

```
AA
BBAA
AABBAA
BBAABBAA
```

where the number of lines of output is given by the input.

This is what I have tried:

```
height = int(input('input height: '))

for row in range(1,height+1):
    for pattern in range(1,row+1):
        if row % 2 != 0:
            for x in range(1, pattern+1, 2):
                print('AA', end = '')
                break
            for x in range(2, pattern+1, 2):
                print('BB', end = '')
                break
        else:
            for x in range(1, pattern+1, 2):
                print('BB', end = '')
                break
            for x in range(2, pattern+1, 2):
                print('AA', end = '')
                break
    print()
```

Which gives:

```
input height: 4
AA
BBBBAA
AAAABBAABB
BBBBAABBAABBAA
```

Comment: If I read your question literally, you say that you are expecting **4 lines** of output. However, your actual example results show **7 lines** of output, and your code clearly produces *x* lines of output, where *x* is the number you input. Please resolve or clarify this discrepancy in the expected results and the actual results.

Comment: Your use of `break` is quite unusual. Did you know, if you have code like `for i in range(1000): do_a_thing(); break`, then the outcome is precisely the same as erasing the loop entirely and writing just `do_a_thing()`?

Comment: What Kevin said. It makes no sense to unconditionally `break` inside a `for` loop; such a loop will execute *at most* one iteration.

Comment: Since your example output has 4 lines, I've changed your actual output to 4 lines.

Comment: @george That is a matter of style. Myself, I use it regularly and happily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the entire thing way more easily. Note that on every line, you just add either "AA" or "BB" to the front of the previous string.

```
height = int(input('input height: '))

laststring = ""
for i in range(height):
    if i%2==0:
        laststring = "AA" + laststring
    else:
        laststring = "BB" + laststring
    print laststring
```

Comment: You're absolutely right... code comprehension fail on my part.

Comment: @VincentKengAn Great! :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Assuming that I have correctly interpreted your desired output. Notice that I'm using the parity, `(ii+jj)%2` to produce the "checkerboard" pattern of alternating "AA" and "BB" that you're trying to produce.

```
height = int(input('input height: '))

for ii in range(1, height+1):
    s = ""
    for jj in range(1, ii+1):
        s += ["AA","BB"][ (ii+jj)%2 ]
    print(s)
```

Results:

```
input height: 7
AA
BBAA
AABBAA
BBAABBAA
AABBAABBAA
BBAABBAABBAA
AABBAABBAABBAA
```

Comment: Thanks too. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  print "".join(["BBAA" for x in range(height/2+1)][-2*height:]

  AABBAABBAABBAA


   for height in range(1,10):
          print "".join(["BBAA" for x in range(height/2+1)][-2*height:]


  AA
  BBAA
  AABBAA
  BBAABBAA
  AABBAABBAA
  BBAABBAABBAA
  AABBAABBAABBAA
  BBAABBAABBAABBAA
  AABBAABBAABBAABBAA
```

Answer (score 0):

The original post was fairly close to a viable solution, except for the unconditional breaks. A solution that is only a slightly modified version of the original:

```
height = int(input('input height: '))

for row in range(1,height+1):
    for pattern in range(1,row+1):
        if row % 2 != 0:
            if pattern % 2 == 1:
                print('AA', end = '')
            else:
                print('BB', end = '')
        else:
            if pattern % 2 == 1:
                print('BB', end = '')
            else:
                print('AA', end = '')
    print()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. Showing the OP how to alter his code to make it do the right thing is a useful answer, even if it's not the most elegant solution to the problem.